# Launching only bolts to remote cluster with Storm streamparse

Tags: python, apache-storm

I am wondering if it is possible to launch not my entire storm topology, but *only* my bolts, leaving my spout(s) running on my local machine? I am using [streamparse](https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse) to write my topology entirely in Python. Would this be possible to do with traditional Storm? If so, is there a streamparse implementation of it? I find no mention of any such functionality in the documentation personally.

I'm still new to storm/streamparse, though I'm pretty sure any/all settings for remote deployment go into the config.json file:

```
{
    "library": "",
    "topology_specs": "topologies/",
    "virtualenv_specs": "virtualenvs/",
    "envs": {
        "prod": {
            "user": "",
            "nimbus": "",
            "workers": [],
            "log": {
                "path": "",
                "max_bytes": 1000000000,
                "backup_count": 10,
                "level": "info"
            },
            "virtualenv_root": ""
        }
    }
}
```